# Python - how to get tweets in real time by hashtag

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, tweetstream

I am looking for a pythonic way to get a stream of tweets by hashtag.
What I found so far is the tweepy package using this code:

```py
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return(True)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print "error"
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["#iPhone"])
```

The problem is that I don't understand how can I get the `consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret` arguments.

I am doing the right thing? Is this the best way to collect tweets by hashtag using python? If so, how to get the that 4 arguments?

Comment: [RTFM](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/auth_tutorial.html#auth-tutorial)!

Comment: thanks dude, just take it easy ;-)